# How do we create an exercise environment like this:

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, exercises

How can we to create an exercise environment like this:
[image]

I tried:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}

\textbf{Câu 3}
Cho $x,y,z$ thỏa mãn $x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$ Chứng minh rằng
$$\dfrac{x^2}{1+2yz}+\dfrac{y^2}{1+2zx}+\dfrac{z^2}{1+2xy}\geqslant \dfrac{3}{5}$$

\end{tcolorbox}
```

But no success. I still can't not placing a colored box around "Câu 3"

Comment: Please clarify what you're (still) trying to achieve. Is it (a) placing a colored box around "Câu 3" and (b) writing "Dien Bien" at the bottom right of the gray box?

Comment: @Mico Yes, I only can't not placing a colored box around "Câu 3".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the following MWE, I used a newly defined `tcolorbox` for the text in teh upper left corner. The symbol is contained in the `fontawesome5` package and can be ccessed through `\faToggleOn`. Spacing around the text, height, width and color of the box can of course be adjusted to suit your needs.

To get rid of the outer box's frame, I used `boxrule=0pt, frame hidden`, to get corners with a 90° angle instead of rounded corners, I added `sharp corners`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,128,128}
\newtcbox{\mybox}{on line,
                  colback=mycolor,
                  fontupper=\bfseries\color{white},
                  boxrule=0pt,
                  arc=5pt, 
                  boxsep=0pt, 
                  left=2pt, 
                  right=2pt, 
                  top=5pt, 
                  bottom=5pt}
  
  
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt, frame hidden, sharp corners]

\mybox{\faToggleOn\; Câu 3}
Cho $x,y,z$ thỏa mãn $x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$ Chứng minh rằng
\[\dfrac{x^2}{1+2yz}+\dfrac{y^2}{1+2zx}+\dfrac{z^2}{1+2xy}\geqslant \dfrac{3}{5}\]

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

---

Updated version that automatically numbers the boxes within their `\section`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,128,128}
                  
                  
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=section,]{mycau}{\faToggleOn\; Câu}%
              {enhanced jigsaw,%
               sharp corners,%
               boxrule=0pt, 
               frame hidden,%
               colbacktitle= mycolor,
               boxed title style={boxrule=0pt, 
                                  frame hidden, 
                                  boxsep=0pt, 
                                  top=5pt, 
                                  bottom=5pt, 
                                  left=2pt, 
                                  right=2pt, 
                                  arc=5pt},
               attach boxed title to top left={xshift=0.5cm,yshift=-8mm},
               fonttitle=\color{white}\bfseries,%
               before upper=\hspace{2.5cm}
               }{th}

  
  
\begin{document}

\begin{mycau}{}{label}
Cho $x,y,z$ thỏa mãn $x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$ Chứng minh rằng
\[\frac{x^2}{1+2yz}+\frac{y^2}{1+2zx}+\frac{z^2}{1+2xy}\geqslant \frac{3}{5}\]
\end{mycau}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you make the black border disappears?

Comment: @tthnew: Sure, I'll add an update on that. Do you want rounded or sharp corners for the outer gray box?

Comment: Yes, I want in like a right angle (as the picture in my post). Thank you!

Comment: Now I'm trying to let it be "auto counter, number within=section", could you help me now dear sir? I tried "  \renewcommand{\ta}{\mmbox{\,\faToggleOn\, Câu\,}}
 \newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=section]{khungx}{\ta}%{ boxrule=0pt,% colback=gray!7!white }{th}" but it doesn't work.

Comment: @tthnew: I have updated my answer accordingly. Probably this new version is closer to the expected output?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Also, if I delete "number within=subsection", then it will be count like 1 - 2 - 3..
When I turn to another section, I want to reset the counter, how I do that?

Comment: @tthnew: You can use `\makeatletter
\setcounter{tcb@cnt@mycau}{0}
\makeatother` to reset the counter. But you will then end up with two or more boxes named "Câu 1" which makes the whole numbering of the boxes somewhat redundant since the box numbers and references to them are now ambiguous.

Comment: I can not reset it by this way. (in Overleaf)

Comment: @tthnew: Where did you place the line of code from my previous comment? It should be placed right before the box which you want to be "Câu 1" again.  What does "I can not reset it" mean specifically? Do you get any error messages or something else?

Comment: Here is the error:https://i.imgur.com/nyK6MKb.png

Comment: @tthnew: It seems as if this is tooo complicated to ba answered in the comments. Please ask a follow up question on this and please also provide a small but cmplete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in this follow up question. Did you notice the 10 error messages? If you get error messages, do not look at the resulting pdf file. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error, thus fix the error messages befor worrying about the output.

Answer (score 3):

The `xcolor` package, which is loaded automatically by the `tcolorbox` package, provides the macros `\colorbox` and `\textcolor`; they come in handy here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tcolorbox,fontawesome5}

% optional: load suitable text and math fonts:
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathfont{Fira Math Regular}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=0pt]
\colorbox{teal}{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\faToggleOn\ Câu 3}}
Cho $x,y,z$ thỏa mãn $x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$ Chứng minh rằng
\[
\frac{x^2}{1+2yz}+\frac{y^2}{1+2zx}+\frac{z^2}{1+2xy} \geqslant \frac{3}{5}
\]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how we can great something like circle, which in front of "Câu 3"?

Comment: I've added the toggle symbol and removed the black frame around the tcolorbox.

Comment: @Mico Should I type  $x,y,z$ or $x$, $y$, $z$?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - I guess the answer depends importantly on what "Cho" and "thỏa mãn" mean. Can you translate? (Sorry, my Vietnamese is nonexistent.)

Comment: "Cho" is mean "Let be given", and "thỏa mãn" is satifying. 
Let be given $x,y,z$ satifying $x^2+y^2+z^2=1.$ Prove that
\[
\frac{x^2}{1+2yz}+\frac{y^2}{1+2zx}+\frac{z^2}{1+2xy} \geqslant \frac{3}{5}
\]

Comment: @minhthien_2016 - Many thanks. Given these instructions, it would indeed be better to write `$x$, $y$, $z$` than `$x,y,z$`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by the answers of @leandriis and @Mico here is how you could combine `tcolorbox` with an exercise package like `xsim`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vietnamese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule = 0pt]
  \tcbox[on line,colback=teal,colframe=teal,coltext=white,size=small]{%
    \faToggleOn\sffamily\bfseries\
    \XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}
    \GetExerciseProperty{counter}%
  }\quad
}{\hfill\textbf{Điện Biên}\end{tcolorbox}}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = custom ,
  exercise/name = Câu
}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  Cho $x,y,z$ thỏa mãn $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Chứng minh rằng
  \[ \frac{x^2}{1+2yz}+\frac{y^2}{1+2zx}+\frac{z^2}{1+2xy} \geqslant \frac{3}{5} \]
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]